# Clique and anti clique in a graph

Tags: combinatorics

I have been stuck for long time on this question:

> Let $A$ and $B$ be sets such that $|A| = 8$ and $|B| = 5$.
>   Calculate how many functions  $f:A\to B$ there are such that there isn't a member of $B$ that has exactly $3$ sources.

I.e., $\forall b\in B\big(|\{a\in A : f(a)=b\}|\neq 3\big)$.

I appreciate your help!

Comment: It's not clear to me what is being asked here...

Comment: @MikeF it's asked to calculate the amount of functions that fulfill the above mentioned requirement. my bet is that the solution based on Ramsey theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: This does not involve Ramsey theory or cliques and anti-cliques; it’s a fairly straightforward application of the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle). Start by counting all of the functions from $A$ to $B$. Then count the functions that violate the condition, and subtract that amount.

To count the ones that violate the condition, let $b\in B$. How many functions from $A$ to $B$ violate the condition at $b$? There are $\binom83$ ways to choose $3$ members of $A$ to be sent to $b$, and there are $4^5$ ways to send the other $5$ members of $A$ somewhere else, so there are $\binom834^5$ functions from $A$ to $B$ that violate the condition at $b$. And there are $5$ possible choices of $b$, so to a first approximation there are $5\binom834^5$ functions from $A$ to $B$ that violate the condition.

However, a function from $A$ to $B$ can violate the condition at more than one point of $B$, and the figure $5\binom834^5$ counts these more than once. Use the inclusion-exclusion principle to correct this overcounting.

Comment: thabks. though I was instructed to use Ransey

Comment: @Ami: You’re welcome. I wonder what was intended: I don’t immediately see any way to use Ramsey theory to get the result.

Comment: one misunderstanding.
I agree with all you wrote but I can't figure out what corrects should be done with $5\binom834^5$.
As I understand, I should calculate all the possible functions and substruct from them the $5\binom834^5$ violations.

Comment: @Ami: Count the functions that are bad at two points of $B$, and subtract that figure. You can do that more or less the same way that I got the figure $5\binom834^5$. First, for each pair of points of $B$ count the functions that are bad at both of those points; then multiply by the number of pairs of points of $B$. That’s the only correction needed, since it’s impossible for a function to be bad at more than two points of $B$.

Comment: got you. thanks again.

Comment: @Ami: You're welcome.